# Karma babel polyfill TypeError

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, babeljs, redux-saga, babel-polyfill

I've been trying to use generator in karma, I've read a lot that I need to include polyfill file before the test file in `karma.conf.js`.

Here is my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
let webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
webpackConfig.entry = './src/index.js';

config = {

    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],

    files: [
      './node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
      // './node_modules/babel-polyfill/browser.js',
      './test/tests.webpack.js'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      './src/index.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
      // './src/**/*.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
      './test/tests.webpack.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
    },

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    ...
}
```

But I got this error everytime I ran `karma start`:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined`

This only shows up if I have the `polyfill` file in the `files`, if I remove it I'll get this error: `RegeneratorRuntime is not defined`

I traced the error and it is coming from this one (redux-saga)

```
var _marked = [selectedDataChanged, selectedInfoChanged, stockAppSaga].map(regeneratorRuntime.mark);

function stockAppSaga() {
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function stockAppSaga$(_context3) {
        while (1) {
            switch (_context3.prev = _context3.next) {
                case 0:
                    _context3.next = 2;
                    return [
                    // takeEvery(
                    //     [actionTypes.SELECTED_TICKER_CHANGED, actionTypes.SELECTED_DATE_CHANGED],
                    //     selectedInfoChanged
                    // ),
                    (0, _effects.takeEvery)([actionTypes.SELECTED_TICKER_CHANGED, actionTypes.SELECTED_DATE_CHANGED], selectedDataChanged)];

                case 2:
                case 'end':
                    return _context3.stop();
            }
        }
    }, _marked[2], this); // this is the error line
}
```

Did I do something wrong in my saga? or is it babel? or somewhere else? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I just fixed the issue, but not really fixed it. I'm guessing it is becaue  I import `index.js` which loads and render all the react app. After I remove import to `index.js` it is working normally. I think I'll stick without importing `index.js` since rendering the whole app is really bad for unit testing. But I still don't really know where is the real cause

Comment: Maybe you mix babel transform operation and polyfills? Only transform is not enough, because you should add runtime polyfill, e,g. regeneratorRuntime & co.